# Chart.js how to set start and end values to plot

Tags: javascript, angularjs, chart.js, angular-chart

I am trying to implement chart.js in my angular app.(horizontal bar chart)

I would like to add the start and end point for the data to be plotted.

In my `dataset` whenever i pass a value the graph plots from 0 to the given value.

`data: [2,6,5,8,7,3,2]`

when this data gets plotted the graph shows from 0 to 2.

But i want to show it from 1 to 2.

Is there a way to pass the start value and end value to be shown in the graph.(not the label the data inside of dataset.)

my data:

```
var data = {
labels: [10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0],
datasets: [
    {
        label: "My First dataset",
        backgroundColor: [
            'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
            'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
            'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
            'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
            'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
            'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
        ],
        borderColor: [
            'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
            'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
            'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
            'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
            'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
            'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
        ],
        borderWidth: 1,
        data: [2,6,5,8,7,3,2],
    }
]
};

var options ={
barShowStroke: false,
  scaleShowGridLines: true,
  scaleOverride: true,
  scaleStartValue: 1,
  scaleStepWidth: 1,      
  responsive: true,
  barBeginAtOrigin: true,
   scales: {
                   xAxes: [{
                           time: {
                unit: 'month'
            },
                           ticks:{
                                   min: 0,
                                   max: 20,
                                   stepSize: 1
                           }
                   }],
                   yAxes: [{
                           display:true}]
    }
};
```

**EDIT:**
[image: This is my graph]

Here i want the y-axis 4 to start from 1 in the x-axis to 2 in the x-axis.
The y-axis 6 to start from 3 in the x-axis to 7 in the x-axis.

Answer (score 0):

Yes possible, check the options provided for (scale) chart below :

```js
var ctx = $("#graphTest").get(0).getContext("2d");


var options = {
      barShowStroke: false,
      scaleShowGridLines: true,
      scaleOverride: true,
      scaleStartValue: 1,
      caleStepWidth: 1,      
      responsive: true,
      barBeginAtOrigin: true
    };
    
var data = {
labels: [10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1],
datasets: [
    {
        label: "My First dataset",
        backgroundColor: [
            'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
            'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
            'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
            'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
            'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
            'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
        ],
        borderColor: [
            'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
            'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
            'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
            'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
            'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
            'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
        ],
        borderWidth: 1,
        data: [2,6,5,8,7,3,2],
    }
]
};


var myBarChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'horizontalBar',
    data: data,
    options: options
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.5.0/Chart.js"></script>
<canvas id="graphTest" width="400" height="190" style="padding-left:10px; padding-right:10px;"></canvas>
```

Comment: I tried but it doesnot work. I have edited my question pls check if it is of any help